# Login with Google account in CodeIgniter with OpenID

Tags: php, codeigniter, openid

I want to implement a login with a Google account using OpenID, but I have no idea how to start this procedure because I have no idea about how to do it. So is there any step by step guides for this so that I can easily implement a Google account login with CodeIgniter in PHP.

I've found only [this](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/) but I cant understand it properly so is there any guides or any libraries to login with a Google account?

Comment: Be aware that since April 2015 Google decommissioned login with OpenID in favor of login with OpenID Connect, a quite different successor, see also: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download **[LightOpenID](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iignatov/LightOpenID/master/openid.php)**. Create the login.php file, and paste the following code into the file.

```
<?php

require_once 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID("my-domain.com");

if ($openid->mode) {
    if ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo "User has canceled authentication !";
    } elseif ($openid->validate()) {
        $data = $openid->getAttributes();
        $email = $data['contact/email'];
        $first = $data['namePerson/first'];
        echo "Identity : $openid->identity <br>";
        echo "Email : $email <br>";
        echo "First name : $first";
    } else {
        echo "The user has not logged in";
    }
} else {
    echo "Go to index page to log in.";
}
```

Create the index.php file, and paste the following code into the file.

```
<?php

require_once 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID("my-domain.com");

$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
$openid->required = array(
    'namePerson/first',
    'namePerson/last',
    'contact/email',
);
$openid->returnUrl = 'http://my-domain.com/login.php'
?>

<a href="<?php echo $openid->authUrl() ?>">Login with Google</a>
```

This is all you need to do. The code has been taken from [Google Login with LightOpenID](http://qpleple.com/how-to-make-people-login-into-your-website-with-their-google-account/).

Comment: Thanks but i get data like email and username but not getting every time only email and language i user all parameter like define in openid.php file but not getting any other parameter

Comment: Download login openid not working. Can you give any other URL.

Answer (score 2):

At first download [openid.php](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/raw/master/openid.php) and put in your codeigniter root folder.

**1. copy the code and save as ..../controller/logingoogle.php**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LoginGoogle extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        require_once 'openid.php';
        $openid = new LightOpenID("localhost");
        $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
        $openid->required = array(
            'namePerson/first',
            'namePerson/last',
            'contact/email',
            'birthDate', 
            'person/gender',
            'contact/postalCode/home',
            'contact/country/home',
            'pref/language',
            'pref/timezone',  
        );
//  $openid->returnUrl = 'http://localhost/login_thirdparty/login_google.php';

    $openid->returnUrl = 'http://localhost/login_thirdparty/codeigniterlogin/index.php/logingoogle/loginAuth';

//  echo '<a href="'.$openid->authUrl().'">Login with Google</a>';

        $data['openid'] = $openid;
        $this->load->view('googleLoginView', $data);
    }

    public function loginAuth()
    {
        $this->login_model->index();
    }
}
```

**2. copy the code and save as ..../views/googleLoginView.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login using google account</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href = "<?php echo $openid->authUrl(); ?>" > Loging Using google account </a>
</body>
</html>
```

**3. copy the code and save as ..../models/login_model.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require 'openid.php';

class Login_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $openid = new LightOpenID("localhost");

        if($openid->mode)
        {
            if($openid->mode == 'cancel')
            {
                echo "User has canceled authentication !";
            }
            elseif($openid->validate())
            {
                $data = $openid->getAttributes();
                $email = $data['contact/email'];
                $first = $data['namePerson/first'];
    //          header("Location: http://speechwithmilo.com/speechtherapy/adminpanel/");
                echo "Identity : $openid->identity <br />";
                echo "Email : $email <br />";
                echo "First name : $first";
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";

//              echo "<meta http-equiv = 'refresh' content = '0; url=http://speechwithmilo.com/speechtherapy/adminpanel/'>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "The user has not logged in";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Go to the login page to logged in";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your solution but encountered an error. Please take a look at my question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173781/login-through-google-in-codeigniter-via-openid