# gmail account login in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know that my question will be a common question, but I have searched for it for the last two weeks and did not find any suitable solution.
My question is about how to login using google account in codeigniter.Every time I get the answer of using openid, but I studied it and still have no idea how to use it.
so please any one help me to mention a suitable library for this.
Please forgive me to ask this question but I am tired of searching this.
Thanks for all,
I found the solution but one problem still remaining, I get only first name, last name and email. How can i get the other information about user after google authenticaton.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Login with google account in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973402/login-with-google-account-in-codeigniter)

Comment: just be specific about what you have done and what the results are. don't apologize - just show your code and the results you get back. this is great topic so don't give up.

Answer (score 0):

How about [this one](https://github.com/openid/php-openid)? It seems to include some examples.

Comment: I  have used this but I get only first name, last name and email. how can i get other information about user after google authentication.

Comment: @user2702406 That is all you need to log a user in with OpenID. It's up to you to use that information to create the user's account on your system. The purpose of OpenID is to authenticate a user, and those details are sufficient to do so. You will need to [read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) for further details - StackOverflow is not here to spoonfeed you.