# Login through Google in Codeigniter via LightOpenID

Tags: codeigniter, lightopenid

I used the instructions given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973402/login-with-google-account-in-codeigniter) answer to setup login through Google via LightOpenId. It's working fine up till the point where it has to check `$openid->mode` to find out whether google has verified the login credentials. The Url received from Google does have the `openid.mode=id_res` parameter. But `$openid->mode` variable from the library still returns false, meaning that it's not verified.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the StackOverflow question you referenced and implement the solution in CodeIgniter with success. Have you tried adding a new line in the routes.php file to direct the return URL to the logingoogle/loginAuth function? Perhaps a default route is circumventing calling the function that you need to complete logging in.